# How to better format these economics diagrams?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

**EDIT:**

I have now created 2 diagrams, here is the first one:

```
% Diagram 1



\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
scale = 1.2,
xmin = 0, xmax = 10,
ymin = 0, ymax = 10,
axis lines* = left,
xtick = {0}, ytick = \empty,
clip = false,
xlabel={Quantity of energy efficient housing}, x label style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
ylabel={Price, costs and benefits (YEN)}, y label style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south, rotate=-90},
]

% Colouring areas
\fill[green, opacity = 0.5] (5, 5) -- (5, 10) -- (7.5,7.5);
% MPB line
\addplot[color = blue, very thick] coordinates {(1, 9) (9, 1)};
% MSB line
\addplot[color = blue, very thick] coordinates {(4, 11) (11, 4)};
% S line
\addplot[color = red, very thick] coordinates {(1, 1) (9, 9)};
% MEB curve
\addplot [color = orange, very thick, <->] coordinates {(8,6.85) (8,2.1)};
% E_1 Dashed lines
\addplot[color = black, dashed, thick] coordinates {(0, 5) (5, 5)
    (5, 0)};
%shaded region
\node [above] at (9.3, 10.7) {Welfare loss};
\draw[-Triangle] (8, 11) to [out = 180, in = 90] (5.5, 7);
% E_opt Dashed lines
\addplot[color = black, dashed, thick] coordinates {(0, 7.5) (7.5, 7.5)
    (7.5, 0)};
% E_1 Coordinate point
\addplot[color = black, mark = *, only marks, mark size = 3pt]
    coordinates {(5, 5)};
% E_opt Coordinate point
\addplot[color = black, mark = *, only marks, mark size = 3pt]
    coordinates {(7.5, 7.5)};
% Axis Labels
% Equillibrium Labels
\node [right] at (5.2, 5) {$E_1$};
\node [above] at (7.5, 7.7) {$E_{opt}$};
% Price Axis Labels
\node [left] at (0, 5) {$P_M$};
\node [left] at (0, 7.5) {$P_{opt}$};
% Quantity Axis Labels
\node [below] at (5, 0) {$Q_M$};
\node [below] at (7.5, 0) {$Q_{opt}$};
% Line Labels
%\node [right] at (8,4) {$MEB$}
\node [right] at (9, 1) {$MPB$};
\node [right] at (9, 9) {$S= MPC= MSC$};
\node [right] at (11,4) {$MSB$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{\textbf{Positive consumption externality in the energy efficient housing market}}
\end{center}
```

The code produces the following output:
[image]

Here is the code for diagram 2:

```
%Diagram 2


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
scale = 1.2,
xmin = 0, xmax = 10,
ymin = 0, ymax = 10,
axis lines* = left,
xtick = {0}, ytick = \empty,
clip = false,
xlabel={Quantity of energy efficient housing}, x label style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
ylabel={Price, costs and benefits (YEN)}, y label style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south, rotate=-90},
]
% Supply and demand curves
\addplot[color = blue, very thick] coordinates {(1, 9) (9, 1)};
\addplot[color = blue, very thick] coordinates {(4, 11) (11, 4)};
\addplot[color = red, very thick] coordinates {(1, 1) (9, 9)};
\addplot[color = red, very thick] coordinates {(4, 1) (11, 8)};
% Dashed lines
\addplot[color = black, dashed, thick] coordinates {(0, 5) (5, 5)
    (5, 0)};
\addplot[color = black, dashed, thick] coordinates {(0, 7.5) (7.5, 7.5)
    (7.5, 0)};
\addplot[color = black, dashed, thick] coordinates {(0, 3.54) (6.54, 3.5)
    (6.5, 0)};
% Coordinate points
\addplot[color = black, mark = *, only marks, mark size = 3pt]
    coordinates {(5, 5)};
\addplot[color = black, mark = *, only marks, mark size = 3pt]
    coordinates {(7.5, 7.5)};
\addplot[color = black, mark = *, only marks, mark size = 3pt]
    coordinates {(6.55, 3.5)};
\node [above] at (5, 5.2) {$E_1$};
\node [above] at (7.5, 7.7) {$E_{opt}$};
\node [above] at (6.5, 3.6) {$E_2$};
\node [left] at (0, 5) {$P_M$};
\node [left] at (0, 3.5) {$P_2$};
\node [left] at (0, 7.5) {$P_{opt}$};
\node [below] at (5, 0) {$Q_M$};
\node [below] at (6.5, 0) {$Q_2$};
\node [below] at (7.5, 0) {$Q_{opt}$};
\node [right] at (9, 1) {$D = MPB$};
\node [right] at (9, 9) {$S = MPC = MSC$};
\node [right] at (11,4) {$MSB$};
\node [right] at (11, 7.7) {$S$ - subsidy};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{\textbf{Effects of the subsidy on the energy efficient housing market}}
\end{center}
```

Which produces:

[image]

How can I improve the formatting of the labels on the axis. To be more specific, how can it be formatted such that it is not in one continuous line. Same for the labelling of the figure. Is it possible to break it up into two lines, such that the second line starts where the first line does?

Also, for diagram 1, if I remove the comment from `\node [right] at (8,4) {$MEB$}` then overleaf refuses to compile, any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: You've created an image with solid lines, dashed lines, and text labels.  What part of your desired image are you having trouble with?  Surely you can see how to get the other 6 lines you want?

Comment: @Teepeemm The labels don't seem to work well. It is not so much the problem of adding the other 6 lines.

Comment: @Teepeemm I have updated my question.

Comment: @Ajay You shouldn't edit your question to include additional requests after you've already gotten answers. If you have follow up question, please ask them as a new question.

Comment: Regarding your last bit about the comment for `\node{$MEB$}`, are you aware it's missing its semicolon?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I wan't sure whether to ask a new question or not as it may seem like i'm trying to gain more reputation. At least what it feels like to me from past experiences.

Comment: @Ajay Don't worry about asking too many questions. As long they are good quality, people won't mind.

Comment: @Teepeemm Thanks, corrected now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=11,
ymin=0, ymax=10,
axis lines*=left,
xtick={0}, ytick=\empty,
clip=false,
xlabel={Quantity of energy efficient housing},
ylabel={Price, costs\\and benefits}, y label style={align=left, at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south, rotate=-90},
]
\fill[pink] (5,5) -- (7.5,7.5) -- (5,10) -- cycle;
\addplot[draw=blue, very thick, samples=2] coordinates {(1, 9) (9, 1)} node[right]{$MPB$};
\addplot[draw=blue, very thick, samples=2] coordinates {(4, 11) (11, 4)} node[right] {$MSB$};
\addplot[draw=red, very thick, samples=2] coordinates {(1, 1) (9, 9)} node[right] {$S$};
\addplot[draw=red, very thick, samples=2] coordinates {(4, 1) (11, 8)} node[right] {$S$ + subsidy};
\addplot[dashed, thick, samples=2] coordinates {(0, 5) (5, 5) (5, 0)} node[below] {$Q_E$} node[left, pos=0] {$P_E$};
\addplot[dashed, thick, samples=2] coordinates {(0, 7.5) (7.5, 7.5) (7.5, 0)} node[below] {$Q_{opt}$} node[left, pos=0] {$P_{opt}$};
\addplot[dashed, thick, samples=2] coordinates {(0, 3.54) (6.54, 3.5) (6.5, 0)} node[below] {$Q_2$} node[left, pos=0] {$P_2$};
\addplot[mark = *, only marks, mark size = 3pt] coordinates {(5, 5)} node[above=3pt] {$E_1$};
\addplot[mark = *, only marks, mark size = 3pt] coordinates {(7.5, 7.5)} node[above=3pt] {$E_{opt}$};
\addplot[mark = *, only marks, mark size = 3pt] coordinates {(6.55, 3.5)};
\node[pin={[pin distance=0.6cm, align=left, font=\small, pin edge={black}]70:{Welfare\\loss}}] at (6,8) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with lines, nodes and filled area]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to label the axis as Price, costs and benefits (YEN) and Quantity of energy efficient housing however, I am not sure how to format it nicely, could you please help? Thanks

Comment: You could use the `currency` package, but as the graph does not have any scale, it does not make sense to use a unit.

Comment: That's not what I meant. In my diagrams above, the axis labels appear in one long line, I want to break it up into 2 lines. Also, for figure 1 I want to move the market such that it is inline with the Positive.

Answer (score 3):

When I run your example, in the log file I get:

```
Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} into your preamble.
 on input line 6.
```

If I follow those directions and add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}` to the preamble, then the labels jump to better positions.

Comment: Thanks, it works now.